# Install4j - animation during installation

Tags: install4j

Is there any way, how to show some animation (video or animated gif) on installation screen during downloading (in case od downloadable components) and during installing files in Install4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Installation" screen is a form screen, so you can add a form component that shows an animation. As of 7.0, install4j does not have a form component that shows videos, but the "Label" form component can show an animated GIF.